# How to improve download speed on Azure VMs?

Tags: azure, networking, virtual-machine

My organization is spinning down its private cloud and preparing to deploy a complete analytics and data warehousing solution on Azure VMs. Naturally, we are doing performance testing so we can identify and address any unforeseen issues before fully decommissioning our datacenter servers.

So far, the only significant issue I've noticed in Azure VMs is that my download speeds don't seem to change at all no matter which VM size I test. The speed is always right around 60 Mbps downstream. This is despite guidance [such as this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-machine-network-throughput) which indicates I should see improvements in ingress based on VM size.

I have done significant and painstaking research into the issue, but everything I've read so far only really addresses "intra-cloud" optimizations (e.g., ExpressRoute, Accelerated Networking, VNet peering) or communications to specific resources. My requirement is for fast download speeds on the open internet (secure and trusted sites only). To preempt any attempts to question this requirement, I will not specifically address the reasons why I can't consider alternatives such as establishing private/dedicated connections, but suffice it to say, I have no choice but to rule out those options.

That said, I'm open to any other advice! What, if anything, can I do to improve download speeds to Azure VMs when data needs to be transferred to the VM from the open web?

Edit: Corrected comment about Azure guidance.

Comment: An F8 VM gives me around 2Gbps for download off of speedtest.net. Could it be that your test is flawed?

Comment: @evilSnobu - great question. I've actually tested a number of methods, used a number of speed tests, tried downloading from FTP sites, downloading from remote SQL servers, even tried different regions and in literally all cases I get about 60 Mbps downstream (with some variance, maybe up to 10%). Is this unusual?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/UyZnCy9.png - This is a DS4, I don't think it matters that much. Your OS/NIC driver might be botched.

Comment: @evilSnobu - as I mentioned though, all the VMs I tested have the same issue. I am not re-using OS disks either. I will say though that I did not mess with the NICs at all. Could that be a clue? I guess another clue would be these VMs I'm testing are totally fresh -- I apply updates, but is it possible some additional drivers need updates? Thanks.

Comment: I have an Azure VM, 4 cores, 16GB RAM. Using XFinity Speed Test, I get about 80 Mbps down and 85 Mbps up.

Comment: @tjw415 The Azure VM size determines it's network bandwidth. Do you have VPN settings? The VPN Gateway SKU also effects network connection throughput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on. @evilSnobu was onto something -- there was something flawed about my tests. Namely, all of them (seemingly by sheer coincidence) "throttled" my data transfers. I was able to confirm this by examining the network throughput carefully. Since my private cloud environment never provisioned enough bandwidth to hit the 50-60 Mbps ceiling that seems to be fairly common among certain hosts, it didn't occur to me that I could eventually be throttled at a higher throughput rate. Real bummer. What this experiment did teach me, is that you should NOT assume more bandwidth will solve all your throughput problems. Throttling appears to be exceptionally common, and I would suggest planning for what to do when you encounter it.